# problema con los headers a la hora de usar flash message

Tags: session, symfony, headers

Cuando hago submit en un formulario obtengo el siguiente error:
Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/var/www/project/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/AbstractDumper.php" at line 176.

Aquí dejo la plantilla twig

```
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" >
      {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

y el controlador

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        
         
        $post = new Post();
         set
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);

        
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            //entity manager
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Article Created');

            // $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add();
            
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post.index'));
        }
```

El problema es que cuando hago submit me indica que los headers ya fueron enviados,
llego hasta el archivo AbstractDumper.php donde parece estar el problema y veo este código que más o menos entiendo:

```
 protected function echoLine(string $line, int $depth, string $indentPad)
    {
        if (-1 !== $depth) {
            fwrite($this->outputStream, str_repeat($indentPad, $depth).$line."\n");
        }
    }
```

Pero no entiendo que debo tocar para que no envíe las cabeceras antes del submit

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema es que al parecer la función dump($post) ya que renderiza los resultados por consola ya mandó también los headers , comentando está línea se resolvió el problema ,espero que está respuesta pueda ayudar a más personas.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Form\PostType;
use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

/**
 * @Route("/post",name="post.")
 */
class PostController extends AbstractController
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->session=new Session();
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/",name = "index")
     * @param Post $post
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showTitles(PostRepository $postRepository)
    {
        $posts = $postRepository->findAll();
        // dump($posts);
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}",name="delete")
     * @param Post
     * @return Response
     */
    public function removeTitle(Post $post)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($post);
        $em->flush();

        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        $session->getFlashBag()->add(
            'removed',
            'the title was removed successfully'
        );
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post.index'));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/create",name = "create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function renderToForm(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->getErrors();
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();
            $estatus="post creado";
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("estatus",$estatus);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post.index'));

        }
        return $this->render('post/form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```